# Python FastAPI race condition even when requests don't share object

Tags: python, fastapi, race-condition

I have a fastAPI app that transforms request payload first for easier processing. (e.g to deal with informal language, reject unknown fields, which fastAPI doesn't provide out-of-box)

I **do** know that this causes race condition (pseudo code):

```
obj = SharedObject()
@wsgi_decorator
def foo(query):
    obj.attribute = query[field1]
    do_math(obj)
```

But even when I initialize `SharedObject` inside the function, it still races.

Here's the minimum reproducible code I've reduced to (runnable)

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

START_QUERY_DICT = { # 1st in tup: default value, 2nd in tup: default type
    'field_1': ('default content', str),
    'field_2': (['human', 'homo sapien'], list)
}
class CustomQuery:
    def __init__(self, json_data) -> None:
        for k, v in START_QUERY_DICT.items(): #initialize all fields with default values
            setattr(self, k, v[0])

        for request_key, request_value in json_data.items():
            if not request_key in START_QUERY_DICT: # no surprise field from payload
                raise AttributeError('Unknown attribute {} from query'.format(request_key))

            if not isinstance(request_value, START_QUERY_DICT[request_key][1]):
                raise TypeError('invalid data type [%s] for field [%s]'%  \
                      (type(request_value).__name__, request_key))

            setattr(self, request_key, request_value)

        if 'human' in self.field_2 or 'homo sapien' in self.field_2:
            # to cater people calling the same thing different names
            self.field_2.extend(['human', 'homo sapien'])
            print(self.field_2)
            self.field_2 = list(set(self.field_2))

app = FastAPI()
@app.post("/")
async def get_results(request:Request):
    query_content = await request.json()
    incoming_query = CustomQuery(query_content)
    return 0
```

Now run it with `uvicorn test:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5099` (assuming you named it test.py)
And execute

```
import requests
for _ in range(1000):
    requests.post("http://localhost:5099", json={"field_1":"hello world"})
```

For each request, the object attribute accumulates even though it's newly inited in each request

```
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:5099 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
['human', 'human', 'homo sapien']
INFO:     127.0.0.1:50221 - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
['human', 'human', 'homo sapien', 'human', 'homo sapien']
INFO:     127.0.0.1:50224 - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
['human', 'human', 'homo sapien', 'human', 'homo sapien', 'human', 'homo sapien']
INFO:     127.0.0.1:50226 - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
['human', 'human', 'homo sapien', 'human', 'homo sapien', 'human', 'homo sapien', 'human', 'homo sapien']
INFO:     127.0.0.1:50228 - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
['human', 'human', 'homo sapien', 'human', 'homo sapien', 'human', 'homo sapien', 'human', 'homo sapien', 'human', 'homo sapien']
```

Weirdly, if I add "field_2": ["human"] to the payload, which shouldn't affect anything, but the problem is gone.

Can someone explain as this is really baffling to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a race condition, you are providing a mutable object (the list in your shared dictionary in key field_2) to a method, and thus that is passed by reference value. A non-FastAPI way of demonstrating this is:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, some_dict: dict[str, list] | None) -> None:
        for k, v in some_dict.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
        print(vars(self))

    def ext(self, key):
        setattr(self, key, getattr(self, key).extend("4"))


this_is_mutable = [1, 2, 3]

for i in range(5):
    obj = A({f"some_key{i}": this_is_mutable})
    obj.ext(f"some_key{i}")
```

Each time the `print()` statement is called, it will be extended with a `4`, see the below output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, '4']
[1, 2, 3, '4', '4']
[1, 2, 3, '4', '4', '4']
[1, 2, 3, '4', '4', '4', '4']
```

The object `this_is_mutable` is passed by reference value, and when changed in the `setattr()` call, it changes is for every object that is holding a reference to that list. The original list is updated.

In your example, comment out the line where you `print()` in your init block, and add this line to your FastAPI endpoint function:  `print(START_QUERY_DICT["field_2"][0])`. It will yield the exact same result as you are seeing now.